# Staggered grid view for an app using LibGDX

Tags: android, windows-phone, libgdx

Has any one ever tried to implement the windows phone kind of UI using LibGDX for an app?
Overall what I would like is to have certain "tiles" displaying buttons. When the tile has a touch event, the tile will expand or start another screen. If there are any leads to this that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no leads for that. You should go for a regular Scene2D setup and use a Table with certain Buttons. Get a start with the [Steigert tutorial](http://steigert.blogspot.de/) to understand the Scene2D. After that take a look at the [wiki for table Layout](http://code.google.com/p/table-layout/). This should give you everything you would need for "the tile optic" (Table with Buttons and listenern and so on). Expanding of the tiles meight work with a regular `Action` from the Scene2D. Just get started and youll find a way.